# what is the pandas ix or iloc multiple condition syntax

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, pandas-loc

Processing the government Office of Foreign Assets Controls (OFAC) list

https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.csv

The 2nd column (the number starting from 0) suggests if this row is an individual, business (-0-), airplane, or vessels information

If I want to keep the both the individual column equal to 'individual' and '-0-', what is the right syntax?  The following codes only work for the individual column equal to 'individual'

```py
name_orig = pd.read_csv('http://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.csv', sep=',', header=None)

name_orig.rename(columns={0: 'id', 1: 'names', 2: 'individual', 11: 'sdn_info'}, inplace=True)

names = name_orig.ix[name_orig.individual == 'individual', ['id', 'names', 'individual', 'sdn_info']]
```

This doesn't seem to work

```py
names = name_orig.ix[name_orig.individual == 'individual' | name_orig.individual == '-0-' , ['id', 'names', 'individual', 'sdn_info']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if you run

```
name_orig.individual.unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['-0- ', 'individual', 'vessel', 'aircraft', nan], dtype=object)
```

The -0- has an extra space.
I think this will work:

```
names = name_orig.ix[((name_orig.individual == 'individual') | (name_orig.individual == '-0- ')), ['id', 'names', 'individual', 'sdn_info']]
```

Comment: Good catch of the space in "-0- "! @Alexandru Pavel!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing parentheses in the mask:

```py
names = name_orig.ix[(name_orig.individual == 'individual') | (name_orig.individual == '-0-'), ['id', 'names', 'individual', 'sdn_info']]
```

or on recent versions:

```py
names = name_orig.loc[(name_orig.individual == 'individual') | (name_orig.individual == '-0-'), ['id', 'names', 'individual', 'sdn_info']]
```

Comment: maybe change `ix` to `loc` since `ix` is deprecated. (assuming their version of pandas is new-ish)

Comment: I assumed that he's using a version where `ix` is working. I will add it to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `loc/iloc`, which will give you the result you are lokking for:

```
names = name_orig[['id', 'names', 'individual', 'sdn_info']].loc[(name_orig['individual'] == 'individual') | (name_orig['individual'] == '-0-')]
```